# Items in list have identical memory locations

Tags: python-2.7

I have the following code:

```
a = [1,2]

b = list(a)

print id(a[0])
print id(b[0])
```

list a and b have different memory locations. but the elements within them have the same location. how can i make these 2 different.

Answer (score 1):

`list` creates a new list, but won't do a deep copy, i.e. clone all the elements inside.

What you need is a `clone` (also known as a `deep copy`). See this answer for good alternatives (and benchmarks) in python: [How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list).